# Cannot access io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification

Tags: java, rest

Me surge este error, no entiendo el porque, intente de todo.

```
public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
    actor.attemptsTo(
            Post.to(CREATE_USER.toString())
                    .with(requestSpecification -> requestSpecification.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .body(body)));
}
```

estoy usando estas dependencias.

```
testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:2.0.0'
testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-rest:2.0.0'
```